# use subclass of CCLayer for CCScrollLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, cocos2d-iphone, ccscrolllayer

I've created a custom class which is a `subclass` of `CCLayer` and trying to use it for `CCScrollLayer`

The way I do it is:

```
//Store the my layers to an NSMutableArray
for (AACustomClassLayer *cardLayer in levels) {
    [layers addObject:cardLayer];
}
```

Under the hood of `CCScrollLayer` it crashes at:

```
- (void) updatePages
{
    // Loop through the array and add the screens if needed.
    int i = 0;
    for (CCLayer *l in layers_)
    {
        l.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
        l.contentSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
        l.position = ccp(  (i * (self.contentSize.width - self.pagesWidthOffset)), 0  );
        if (!l.parent)
            [self addChild:l];
        i++;
    }
}
```

The implementation for the AACustomClassLayer class (subclass of CCLayer) looks like:

```
-(id)initWithChapter:(AALevel *)level {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
//Here I'm adding the CCSprite to my layer

  }
    return self;
}
```

UPDATE:

**Crash log**

```
2012-04-20 14:12:12.344 [15780:10a03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setAnchorPoint:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x884ab40'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1a75022 0x200fcd6 0x1a76cbd 0x19dbed0 0x19dbcb2 0xd013f 0xcfe2b 0x102370 0x44c15 0xbe45f 0x8a94be 0x8aa274 0x8b9183 0x8b9c38 0x8ad634 0x282def5 0x1a49195 0x19adff2 0x19ac8da 0x19abd84 0x19abc9b 0x8a9c65 0x8ab626 0xbda06 0x22e5)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: According to the log, looks like l is a NSDictionary rather than CCLayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it!

```
for (AACustomClassLayer *cardLayer in levels) {
    cardLayer = [[AACustomClassLayer node] autorelease];
    [layers addObject:cardLayer];
}
```

Comment: cardLayer should be an autoreleased object.

Comment: @meccan: Thanks! Still having problems; Do you know why it does not display my ccsprites to the CCScrollLayer?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a conditional check in your `for` loop that determines if the object you are getting from enumeration is in fact a CCLayer. Your crash log states that the `anchorPoint` setter was not available on some object, presumably on an object in your `layers_` array since that is the code you have posted that deals with anchorPoints.

Enumeration is convenient, but you are casing all objects to `CCLayer` when it is possible that one of them is not. I don't know where you are adding objects to `layers_` but is it possible you are adding an object that is not actually a `CCLayer` ?